# Get the last version of a record in sql

Tags: sql

I want to code a query in SQL to get the first and last version of each record. Lets said this is my main table, with the Record column working as ID, and other column named Version to store the changes. My problem is, I dont know how many version an ID (record) would get, the only rule is ">=1".

[image]

In the end, the result im looking for is a table like this, to calculate the difference in quantity between the first and last version

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data as tables with text, so people can copy the text and try out possible solutions. Or even better create a fiddle and share the url.

Comment: If 20 vs 15 = 5, then why isn't 40 vs 42 = -2 (negative 2)? Do you just want the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: What's the database? Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc...

Comment: As a very general rule, SQL is not well suited to problems like this that do processing on multiple related records where output rows are handled differently.  It can be done, but it's usually ugly.  This would be better handled in a programming language.

Comment: @TheImpaler SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which database you are using, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select record, version, quantity,
  case when rnd = 1 then 
    abs(lag(quantity) over(partition by record order by version)
    - quantity) end as difference
from (
  select *
  from (
    select t.*,
      row_number() over(partition by record order by version) as rn,
      row_number() over(partition by record order by version desc) as rnd  
    from t
  ) x 
  where rn = 1 or rnd = 1
) y
```

Result:

```
 record  version  quantity  difference 
 ------- -------- --------- ---------- 
 doc1    1        20        null       
 doc1    3        15        5          
 doc2    1        40        null       
 doc2    2        42        2          
 doc3    1        32        null       
 doc3    4        26        6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hyam_ba3).